# pass in, and evaluate, options in group_by function in the dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

With a data_frame:

```
Col_1  counts   Date_Column
   1     23     2015-01-01
   2     44     2015-06-11
   3     31     2015-07-21
   2     22     2015-01-01
```

I am aggregating with the dplyr package like this:

```
aggregated <- data_frame %>% group_by(Col_1,week=week(Date_Column)) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), -Date_Column)
```

But I would like to contain this inside a function as such:

```
collapse_frame <- function(data_frame, group_by_option, minus_option) {
    aggregated <- data_frame %>% group_by(group_by_option) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), -minus_option)
    return()
}
```

But the group_by_option and minus_option don't get evaluated properly.

Is there a way to pass in these options, and have them evaluated inside a function?

```
collapse_frame(my_frame, 'Col_1,week=week(Date_Column)', 'Date_Column')
```

I have tried using the following:

```
eval(parse(text=group_by_option))
as.formula(group_by_option)
eval(group_by_option)
```

Comment: Welcome to SE dplyr. [Do some reading](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) (and `vignette('nse', 'dplyr')`), get fed up, and try to avoid it.

Comment: Indeed. Works with one column, but not 2.

Comment: You can use the `.dots` argument, which can take a list.

Comment: There it is...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per @alistaire's suggestion:

list of columns to group by:

```
group_by_list <- list(Col_1, Date_Column)
```

And a method for passing in arbitrary frames and column names:

```
collapse_frame_by_sum <- function(data_frame, group_by_choice, minus_choice) {
    collapsed_frame <- data_frame %>% group_by_(.dots=group_by_choice) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), -eval(parse(text=minus_choice)))
    collapsed_frame <- data.frame(collapsed_frame)
    return(collapsed_frame)
}
```

Run as:

```
result <- collapse_frame_by_sum(my_frame, group_by_list, 'Date_Column')
```